# How do I rotate a shape in python by +/- x degrees using numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rotation

I am new to python and I am trying to rotate a shape (it is a closed circle with cutouts inside) by +/- x degrees. The degree value is given by user interaction (user chooses the amount of degrees to rotate the figure by).

The function has to operate on the entire shape (including the cut outs) and I want to do it using numpy arrays.

I am new to python, and I am not really sure where to even start with it, so I don't have any coherent code to post, otherwise I would.

For every curve in the shape, I am trying to convert it to the following:

```
x' = xr + (x-xr)cos(angle) - (y - yr) sin(angle)
```

and

```
y' = yr + (x-xr)sin(angle) + (y - yr) cos(angle)
```

where `(x',y')` is the point in the output, `angle` = angle of rotation, `(xr, yr)` = point being rotated about, and then I want to return the rotated (modified) shape.

I am going to keep working on it, and see if I can come up with something better to post, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you have any questions, or if it needs clarification, let me know.

Comment: How is the shape defined/stored right now? Do you have functions, arrays of x and y values, an image/mask type array, or something else?

Comment: I am trying to define: rotate(shape, angle, xr, yr) where shape is title, diagram and angle is the angle given by the user. And xs,ys = curve (or tuple xs and ys = curve). I'm not sure if that answers your question..

Comment: I still don't understand what format/type `shape` is, and `title, diagram` doesn't help me either :P  If `shape` is just some set of `x` and `y` points, then you've already answered your question yourself (and @JAC has restated it with some extraneous broadcasting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your notation and assuming that both `x,y` are lists of the same size containing your curve, this is what I would do to get an array x_new:

```
xr_arr = xr * ones(len(x))
yr_arr = yr * ones(len(y))    
angle_arr = angle * ones(len(x))
x_new = xr_arr + (x - xr_arr)*cos(angle_arr) - (y - yr_arr)*sin(angle_arr)
```

This assumes you have included `from numpy import *` in your script. The array y_new can be obtained in the same way. If you had multiple curves you could do similarly using two-dimensional arrays.

> EDIT: As Jaime mentions below, if `x,y` are numpy arrays, there is no need to vectorize xr,yr, and angle.

Comment: What is the ones for? Sorry, I haven't seen that notation before. I imported numpy as np. x and y are indeed the same size containing the curve... but I have not converted them to array. If that makes sense.

Comment: It just creates an array of the same size as x or y that contains the value one at each position. I see, so do you have `x,y` as lists? If that is the case, this code would work too. Otherwise take a look at [this reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html) to see how to import data into an array.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are numpy arrays, you can write `x - xr` directly, without creating the `xr_arr` before and broadcasting will take care of making it work properly. You similarly don't need to expand the angle into an array the isze of `x` and `y`: multiplying by `sin(angle)` should do it.